# Sum of count with where query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to divide two count using where conditions

```
(SELECT COUNT([Main_Status]) 
 FROM [V_Incidents_Combined] 
 WHERE [Main_Status] = N'open') / 
(SELECT COUNT([Main_Status]) 
 FROM [V_Incidents_Combined] 
 WHERE [Main_Status] = NT'Closed')
```

I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
> Incorrect syntax near '/'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two subqueries, but you're not *doing* anything with the result of the calculation of those.

You need to select the final result

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT Count(vic.Main_Status)
    FROM V_Incidents_Combined vic
    WHERE vic.Main_Status = N'open'
   ) / (
    SELECT Count(vic.Main_Status)
    FROM V_Incidents_Combined vic
    WHERE vic.Main_Status = N'Closed'
   );
```

Having said that, you can do this more efficiently in a single level using conditional aggregation.

Also note that since `Main_Status` is not null, the result of `COUNT(Main_Status)` will be the same as `COUNT(*)`. And `COUNT` returns an integer, you probably want to make it into a decimal.

```sql
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN vic.Main_Status = N'open' THEN 1 END) * 1.0
  / COUNT(CASE WHEN vic.Main_Status = N'Closed' THEN 1 END)
FROM V_Incidents_Combined vic;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your statement boils down to this expression:

```
(a) / (b)
```

In SQL you always have to specify what you want to do with the expression result, like this:

- `SELECT (a) / (b)`
- `PRINT (a) / (b)`
- `SET @variable = (a) / (b)`

etc.

So if you do one of those things, it should start working.